# HTML input to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have tried a lot of silly measures at this point, however, I am wanting a value to be entered into an HTML input. Click a button. That input then goes through a function and is stored. I have written a very simple script and still can't get it to work.

I am feeling quite the fool at the moment. So what appears to happen is that when I first hit the button it runs the function as expected then it goes back to the original HTML page and loses the return value and puts it back to null.

This means further down the script I can't run anything else and I can't work with the value anymore.

Thanks in advance. I am noob learning.

Snippet

```js
function number()
{
 var x = document.getElementById("input1");
 var value = x.value;  
 console.log(value);
 
 return value;
}


var inputNumber1 = number(value);

console.log("This is inputNumber1: " + inputNumber1);

function alert()
{
 console.log("Testing!");
}

console.log("Run on further");
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <form>
        <label>Input Number 1</label>
        <input id="input1" type="number"> 
        <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="number()" >Submit2</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" id="button2" >Submit</button> -->
    </form>

    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert()">Alert Me</button>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you want to store the value/values?

Comment: At the moment I want to store them as variaibles as I need manipulate them and send them on further. In this case I honestly be glad if I could get beyond the function and run some of the other console.logs. And maybe not run the script before page load.

Comment: You're doing `var inputNumber1 = number(value);` when the page first loads, so the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything into the input.

Comment: Or in a variable at the end. Most times I will manipulate the input in the function.

Comment: Also, `number()` doesn't take an argument, so you shouldn't have `value` in there.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I removed that but it doesn't change the the lack of continuation in the script. I think at the point I was trying things. Sorry I have being trawling the internet for anything. So i have tried a bunch of odd ideas

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re _actually_ trying to do. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more on your use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array as global variable for storing the number by clicking the formular button.

You need not to call the function directly in the code, because at this time, no input is available.

```js
function number(){
   var value = document.getElementById("input1").value;
   numbers.push(value); // store this number
   document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = numbers.length + 1; // update count
   console.log(numbers);
}

var numbers = []; // store all numbers
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Input Number <span id="count">1</span></label>
    <input id="input1" type="number"> 
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="number()" >Submit2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Not quite what I was after but I love this and am keeping it for future reference. I wouldn't have thought of this! I also have a need for this. Thanks

Comment: and what do you want?

Comment: Actually I take the previous comment back this is a far better solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `number()` before the user has entered anything.

Store the value when you click on one button, and then show it when you click on the second button.

```js
var inputNumber1;

function number() {
  var x = document.getElementById("input1");
  inputNumber1 = x.value;
}

function alert() {
  console.log("The number you entered was: " + inputNumber1);
}

console.log("Silly message!");
```

```html
<label>Input Number 1</label>
<input id="input1" type="number">
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="number()">Submit2</button>

<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert()">Alert Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here as I am still trying to learn so far from any good, but how come if was I was to have a console.log("Silly Message"); underneath it will not run? Ie the script will not continue to run.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this has being really insightful and thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
// Use value as global 
var value ;

function number(){

 var x = document.getElementById("input1");
 value= x.value;  
 console.log(value); 
return value;

}


var inputNumber1 = number();
console.log("This is inputNumber1: " + inputNumber1);

function alert(){
    console.log("Testing!");
}

console.log("Run on further");
```

Answer (score 0):

Important message , you can't use reserved words like alert , (number) Number etc. Bad idea. Always check in console if you not sure is it reserved or not. 
  Also :

```
 <input id="input1" type="number">
```

you need to put value tag here .

```js
function MyNumber(){

 var x = document.getElementById("input1");
 console.log("test x.value : " + x.value);
 return x.value;  

}


console.log("This is inputNumber1: " + MyNumber());

function MyAlert(){
    alert(MyNumber())
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label>Input Number 1</label>
   <input id="input1" type="number" value="ss" /> 
   <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="MyNumber()" >Submit2</button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="MyAlert()">Alert Me</button>
    </div>
```